# Why not chain java.util.stream.Stream#forEach

Tags: java, java-8

In java 8,`java.util.stream.Stream#forEach` consider as a replacement for traditional for-loop. But why not this is not chain function.Says it return void instead of `Stream<T>` it self.

Like this

```
Arrays
    .stream(Girls.toArray())
    .forEach(Girls::getUp)
    .forEach(Girls::dressUp)
    .filter(/* Top 10 Girls */)
    .forEach(Gay.getMe()::gotGirl)
    .endFilter()// Not an API, but it means remove last filter
    .filter(/* Worst 10 Girls */)
    .forEach(Gay.get(0)::gotGirl)


girls = Arrays
    .stream(Girls.toArray());
girls.forEach(g->{g.getUp();g.dressUp()});
girls.filter(/* Top 10 Girls */)
    .forEach(Gay.getMe()::gotGirl);
girls.filter(/* Worst 10 Girls */)
    .forEach(Gay.get(0)::gotGirl);
```

The first is nice than second one.But the first one got worse performance.

So, why `forEach` is not chainable ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because forEach is a terminal operation. It forces the stream to consume all its elements and call the consumer for each of them. Once that is done, the stream has been consumed, and can't be reused.

A Stream has as many intermediate operations as you want, but can have just one terminal operation.

Answer (score 28):

The methods you are looking for exist and are called [Stream::peek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) and [Stream::map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). With `Stream::peek`, the above code might look as follows.

```
Arrays
    .stream(Girls.toArray())
    .peek(Girls::getUp)
    .peek(Girls::dressUp)
    .filter(/* Top 10 Girls */)
    .peek(Gay.getMe()::gotGirl)
    ...
```

Comment: However, note that having side-effects in `peek()` or `map()` behavioral parameters that may interfere with the source, or affect the result of other stream operations, is a no-no.  The `peek()` method is really there just for debugging/logging, not for computing the result; similarly, `map()` should be used only for transforming, not for hiding side-effects.

Answer (score 9):

The `forEach` operation is indeed a *terminal operation* and is thus not chainable, but it is possible to compose several operations (consumers, in this case) into a single `forEach` call. For example:

```
    Consumer<String> c1 = s -> System.out.println(s + "1");
    Consumer<String> c2 = s -> System.out.println(s + "2");
    Consumer<String> c3 = s -> System.out.println(s + "3");
    Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
          .stream()
          .forEach(c1.andThen(c2).andThen(c3));
```

Unfortunately it doesn't appear possible to write the lambdas inline without a bunch of ugly casting.

Answer (score 5):

Continuing from [Stuart Marks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24235468/4872798), it is possible to write the lambdas inline but only the first consumer needs to be cast :

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").forEach(
    ((Consumer<String>) s -> System.out.println(s + "1"))
    .andThen(s->System.out.println(s + "2"))
    .andThen(s -> System.out.println(s + "3"))
);
```

Comment: Every time you do an explicit cast a fairy dies.

Answer (score 3):

Chaining with `andThen` is indeed the way to go, but we need some syntactic sugar to make it pretty:

```
public class Consumers {
    public static <T> Consumer<T> of(Consumer<T> base) {
        return base;
    }
}
```

This allows us to do:

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
      .stream()
      .forEach(Consumers.of(s -> System.out.println(s + "1"))
                        .andThen(s -> System.out.println(s + "2"))
                        .andThen(s -> System.out.println(s + "3")));
```

Or (shorter):

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
      .forEach(Consumers.of(s -> System.out.println(s + "1"))
                        .andThen(s -> System.out.println(s + "2"))
                        .andThen(s -> System.out.println(s + "3")));
```

(since `forEach`is available directly on the collection)

Comment: Using forEach in the collection prevents you from doing in a parallel way. Another thing, what is the point of the `Consumers` class? You can use your `Consumer` directly instead of passing it to a method and returning without doing nothing.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Without the helper method you will have to cast `s -> System.out.println(s + "1")` to `Consumer<String>`. And as we all know, casting kills kittens :)

Answer (score 0):

As `andThen` is defined in Java 8 as

```
default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t) -> { accept(t); after.accept(t); };
}
```

you can easily create your own composite `Consumer<T>` for any number of your functions

```
class CompositeConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    private final List<Consumer<T>> funcs;

    CompositeConsumer(List<Consumer<T>> funcs) {
        this.funcs = funcs;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
        for (Consumer<T> func: funcs) {
            func.accept(t); 
        } 
    }
}
```

and use it for any number of your functions at once

```
List<Consumer<String>> funcs = ...
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
      .forEach(new CompositeConsumer(funcs));
```